# Counting occurrences in several columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm making an app that shows people movies to rate, a-la hot-or-not. I'd like to write a query that gets me the number of times a movie has been rated. The table for ratings looks like this:

```
| id | winner | loser |
| 1  |   1    |   2   |
| 2  |   2    |   3   |
| 3  |   1    |   3   |
```

I can get the number of times a movie has "won" by running a query like this:

```
SELECT winner, count(winner) AS number_of_wins
  FROM movie_results
  GROUP BY winner
  ORDER BY number_of_wins DESC;
```

But I'd like to get another query that shows the total number of times a movie was pitched against other movies, i.e. the number of times a movie has appeared to be rated, whether it was rated above or below the other movie. What is the easiest way to achieve this, using only SQL queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one method, using `union all`:

```
select movie, count(*) as nummatches, sum(win) as numwins
from ((select winner as movie, 1 as win from match_results) union all
      (select loser, 0 from match_results)
     ) wl
group by movie;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a `full join` between two derived tables where each table contains the number of losses and wins for each player.

```
select 
    coalesce(winner,loser) player,
    coalesce(number_of_wins,0) number_of_wins,
    coalesce(number_of_losses,0) number_of_losses,
    coalesce(number_of_wins,0) + coalesce(number_of_losses,0) number_of_matches 
from (
    select winner, count(*) number_of_wins
    from movie_results
    group by winner
) winners full join (
    select loser, count(*) number_of_losses
    from movie_results
    group by loser
) losers on losers.loser = winners.winner
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/980d6/3